# how to use ajax in WordPress also which and where including all coding files?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am new at WordPress, I was using ajax in CodeIgniter but now I want to use ajax in WordPress,

but I don't know which file I should include and where to ? please help me.

I am using Avada theme.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code of using ajax in WordPress in the front end.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {
 wp_enqueue_script('like_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/post-like.js', '1.0', 1 );
 wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
 'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajaxnonce')
 ));
}

?>
```

In above Code we have used `wp_localize_script()` function which **Localizes a registered script with data for a JavaScript variable.**  Inside which we have used an array for **url** and **nonce**.

now we can use **url** and **nonce** variables in our javascript code easily.

if you want execute the script  to fire on the front-end for both visitors and logged-in users, then you need to use these hooks:

```
<?php
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_post_like', 'my_post_like' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_post_like', 'my_post_like' );
 ?>
```

where `my_post_like()` is our defined function which will be invoked once ajax request is fired .

```
var $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();
 (function($wk_jq){ 
    $wk_jq(window).bind("load",function(){
    $wk_jq(".post-like a").click(function(eve){ 
        heart = $wk_jq(this);
        post_id = heart.data("post_id"); 
        $wk_jq.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_var.url,   // variable defined above with an array for url and nonce 
            data: "action=my_post_like&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&post_id="+post_id,  // Action variable defines the name of the php function which proceess ajax request based on the variable we have passed   
            success: function(count){
                 // Do your stuff here once ajax response is returned
            }
        });
        eve.preventDefault();
                
        return false;
        });
    });
})($wk_jq);
```

In our above code we also passing a nonce variable along with the post id for security reasons

```
<?php
function my_post_like()
{
  $nonce = $_POST['nonce']; 
 // Verify nonce field passed from javascript code
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajaxnonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');
   
  if(isset($_POST['post_like']))
  {
    // do your stuff and return count;
    echo $count;
    }
    else
      echo "default text";
  }
  exit;
}
?>
```

If you have noticed, in above code we have used exit ajax in wordPress returns 0 for any function, so we must use exit at the end of the function

That’s all for how to use Ajax in wordPress

Comment: which files I need to include these lines of code?

Comment: Function should add on function.php & script will be add on your template